# In Android, can a file be moved to inside the app's private directory?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-file

I have a file in the downloads directory. Let's call it `OldFile`, of the File class.

I seem to be move it anywhere I like using `OldFile.renameTo(File(some new file path))` UNLESS the new file path is inside the application's private file directory as obtained from `context.filesDir`.

This Kotlin snippet works, for instance:

```
val newFileLocation = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/test.txt")
oldFile.renameTo(newFileLocation)
```

but this snippet fails silently, throwing no exception, leaving `oldFile` completely unchanged:

```
val newFileLocation = File(context?.filesDir?.absolutePath + "/test.txt")
oldFile.renameTo(newFileLocation)
```

Is there some rule against using File.renameTo to move a file into the filesDir path?

How am I supposed to go about it?

thanks

John

Comment: If all else fails-  read in the file as binary data, write it out as binary data where you want it to go, then delete the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renameTo() works only for files on the same 'partition'.

Apparently getFilesDir() is on a different partition.

Comment: That would seem to explain it, even though the downloads directory and the filesDir are both on the same storage device, and external storage is a different storage device! Thanks!